# Mysql MAX value and Last Record at the same time

Tags: mysql

If you have table with 2 fields:

ID | AMOUNT

How do you get the max(AMOUNT) and the amount of the last entered record ( order by id desc ) using 1 query ?

Thanking you

Comment: can you give sample data with your desired result?

Answer (score 1):

```
select amount as last_amount, 
      (select max(amount) from your_table) as max_amount
from your_table
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(amount) FROM table) as Max,
    (SELECT amount FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as Last
```